# How to pivot this tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Considering this tibble, I'm trying to use tidyr::pivot_longer() to convert it...
Many thanks in advance !

```
table_initiale <- tribble(
~categorie, ~`2016m2017`, ~`2017m2017`, ~`2017m2018`, ~`2018m2018`,
"ETI",   63576,  64516,  62954,  67540
)

# What I would like :  

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  annee meth2017 meth2018
  <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2016     63576       NA
2 2017     64516    62954
3 2018        NA    67540
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `pivot_longer` -

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(table_initiale, 
                    cols = -categorie, 
                    names_to = c('anne', '.value'), 
                    names_pattern = '(\\d+)(m\\d+)')

#  categorie anne  m2017 m2018
#  <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 ETI       2016  63576    NA
#2 ETI       2017  64516 62954
#3 ETI       2018     NA 67540
```

You can rename and remove columns to match the exact expected output if needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `names_pattern` argument to split the existing column (see [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/pivot-longer-on-multiple-column-sets-pairs/43958/10) from the RStudio Community):

```r
table_initiale %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!categorie,
                      names_to = c("annee", ".value"),
                      names_pattern = "(.*)m(.*)") %>% 
  dplyr::select(annee,
                meth2017 = `2017`,
                meth2018 = `2018`)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   annee meth2017 meth2018
#>   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 2016     63576       NA
#> 2 2017     64516    62954
#> 3 2018        NA    67540
```